# Как вывести все связи много ко многим через findAll?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Пытаюсь вывести все связи через findAll но крашится ошибка
TypeError: left.getMains is not a function
Если заменяю на findOne - все работает, но мне надо вывести именно все связи

Comment: дайте мне минуту, сейчас звоню экстрасенсу чтобы он мне прислал код по факсу

Comment: передайте экстрасенсу, что в данном случае код не требуется

Comment: Факс сломался(( *xd*

Comment: Модели, ассоциации и запрос в студию!

Answer (score -1):

Нашел у себя в закромах, надеюсь поможет

```js
// код асинхронной функции
const Table = sequelize.define('table_name', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {freezeTableName: true});
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
return await sequelize.sync().then(()=>(Table.findAll({where: _data}))).then((r)=>{
    try{sequelize.close();}catch(e){}
    return r;
}).catch((e)=>{
    log('error', e);
});
```